# Getting started with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) beacon development

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, beacon, eddystone

I have a couple of questions concerning BLE beacons:

1) **Are beacons based on nRF51822 chip the best solution?** *Or are there any other chips better than nRF51822?*   I want to take up BLE beacon development and struggling to find the right hardware for these needs. As a novice developer I want the beacon to be as cheap as possible in order not to waste money in case of a failure.

2) **Is it possible to buy pure Eddystone beacon (not iBeacon)?** The reason for choosing Eddystone  is that Eddystone is capable of broadcasting URLs that are essential for me.
The second question stems from my failed attempts to find a pure Eddystone beacon on Chinese electronics sites like alibaba.com or aliexpress.com where the only firmware available is iBeacon. But iBeacon is not an option because it can't broadcast URL the way Eddystone does.

**Apart from the above questions It would be great if someone wrote a quick guide for taking up BLE development** **with Eddystone** and covered basic topics like: chip to use, beacon model, best website to buy beacons at, etc.

Thanks in advance,
Pavel

Answer (score 2):

1) I've worked with Estimote beacons and Chinese beacons from Amazon and in my opinion, they do not differ in terms of accuracy too much. Especially for prototyping, I'd buy cheaper ones to test if your use case can be satisfied with BLE beacons. If it is too inaccurate with Chinese beacons, chances are that it won't work with more expensive ones either.

2) Why do you need the URL broadcast? If the app is going to use the url, it would have to be connected to the internet. Therefore, you can just query the beacon's IDs to a web service to get back an URL and use that. Personally, I think this is a better approach as you can configure the web service from anywhere to change the url for beacons where as if you want to change the URL of the Eddystone, you have to go to the beacon to configure it.

Answer (score 2):

The nRF51822 is a common implementation, is flexible, well understood and can be very inexpensive.  Be aware though that development costs, add on circuitry for power and/or peripherals, and packaging can easily eclipse the Bluetooth chip when you get to production cost savings.

If you want to buy an off the shelf beacon, most models supporting Eddystone also support iBeacon, simply because supporting both adds no additional hardware cost.  Newer Radius Networks and Estimote beacons all support both.  And, yes, cheaper generic Chinese suppliers often have bulk manufactured inventory from before Eddystone existed at only support iBeacon.